# API Google Maps não está funcionando usando Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para Android usando Cordova, estou fazendo a geo localização trabalhando com a latitude e longitude do usuário, pegando esses dados, eu crio o mapa (a posição do usuário), e com isso eu crio os *markers* (os marcadores no mapa). No desktop funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu vou emular no celular, nada acontece.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1-7.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsivo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script>
        function _GET(name)
        {
          var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
          var itens = url.split("&");

          for(n in itens)
          {
            if( itens[n].match(name) )
            {
              return decodeURIComponent(itens[n].replace(name+"=", ""));
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
        var log = _GET("log");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maps.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()" id="tela-login">

        <script>

            function initialize() {

                function _GET(name){

                    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
                    var itens = url.split("&");

                    for(n in itens){
                        if( itens[n].match(name) ){
                            return decodeURIComponent(itens[n].replace(name+"=", ""));
                        }
                    }
                    return null;

                }

                var latitude = _GET("lat");
                var longitude = _GET("lon");

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                var settings = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);     

                    // AQUI É UM INDICADOR, E AQUI VAI O LOOP

                    var imagemPin = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/google.png",
                        new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(25,50));

                    var Posicao = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                    var Marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: Posicao,
                        map: map,
                        icon: imagemPin,
                        title:"LUGAR",
                        zIndex: 3});

                    google.maps.event.addListener(Marcador, "click", function() {
                        infoColinasWindow.open(map,Marcador);
                    });

                    var colinasString = "<div class='muralPin'><div class='imagemPin'><img src='felipe.jpg' style='width: 60%;'></div><div class='textoPin'><p>Olá eu sou o Felipe</p></div></div>";                

                    var infoColinasWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: colinasString
                    });

                    //FIM DO INDICADOR

                    // AQUI É UM INDICADOR, E AQUI VAI O LOOP

                    var imagemPin = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/google.png",
                        new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(25,50));

                    var Posicao = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.403954,-47.5717276);

                    var Marcador2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: Posicao,
                        map: map,
                        icon: imagemPin,
                        title:"LUGAR",
                        zIndex: 3});

                    google.maps.event.addListener(Marcador2, "click", function() {
                        infoColinasWindow2.open(map,Marcador2);
                    });

                    var colinasString2 = "<div class='muralPin'><div class='imagemPin'><img src='mario.jpg' style='width: 60%;'></div><div class='textoPin'><p>Olá eu sou o Mario</p></div></div>";     

                    var infoColinasWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: colinasString2
                    });

                    //FIM DO INDICADOR

            }

            </script>
        <div class="bartop-index-app">
            <div class="sair-index-app">

            </div>
            <div class="texto-bartop-index-app">
                <img src="img/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="login-v-index-app">
                <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/10440811_793958303957393_4162157372130782847_n.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapaMural">
            <div id="map_canvas" style=""></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código JS:

```
<script>
    if (navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosicao, displayError);
    }

    function getPosicao(position){
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;

      var lon = position.coords.longitude;

      window.location = 'mapaAll.html?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon;
     }

     function displayError(error) {
      var errors = {
        0: "Erro Desconhecido",
        1: "Permissão negada",
        2: "Posição indisponível",
        3: "Timeout"
      };
      alert("Ocorreu um erro: " + errors[error.code]);
    }
    </script>
```

No código JS, eu pego a localização atual, e uso `window.location = 'mapaAll.html?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon;` passando a latitude e longitude pro arquivo HTML.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Seu código apresenta alguns problemas. A primeira coisa a ser observada é que quando você estiver desenvolvendo aplicativos com `Cordova` ou `PhoneGAP` você deve sempre verificar pelo evento [deviceready](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

A forma como o Cordova funciona é bem simples, ele cria uma espécie de navegador que executa seu HTML. Ele também registra algumas funções no JavaScript para tornar a integração nativa.
Este processo leva um certo tempo, por isso o Cordova adiciona este Listeners e depois dispara o evento `deviceready`.

O que pode estar acontecento é que você chama funções do Geo Location antes do Cordova ter criado a interface entre o Android.

Outros problemas que é possível observar em seu código é que na sua função `_GET` você faz um loop procurando por parâmetros toda vez, verifique se isso é realmente necessário, isso pode tornar aplicativos lentos, especialmente nos smartphones.
Uma peculiaridade é que o Android pode achar que sua aplicação travou se em algum momento algum loop não tiver fim, isso pode deixar o seu aplicativo completamente travado durante o processo. Procure faz todos os processos voltados a eventos.

Na parte do seu código que você armazena os dados de longitude e latitude, você utiliza o seguinte código.

```
  var latitude = _GET("lat");
  var longitude = _GET("lon");
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
```

Você esta criando um mapa com os dados conseguidos da função `_GET`, ou seja a longitude e latitude deve ser passado por junto a URL. Ou seja com o código apresentado você não faz nenhuma chamada a API do Cordova. Já na parte de seu código que lida com o Cordova, você pode implementar de forma diferente, você tenta atualizar o URL do navegador para criar o mapa, porém isso pode fazer a página recarregar, o que não é algo que você possa ficar fazendo no Android. Verifique também se você adicionou o plugin responsável pela `GeoLocation` no Android.

Uma solução seria ajustar o seu código para aguardar o Cordova disparar o `deviceready` ou fazer algum tipo de verificação se o seu aplicativo esta em um SmartPhone ou  se esta sendo executado no navegador. Só então criar o mapa com base na localização.

Outra coisa que pode ser melhorada é que atualmente você pega localização com dados passados pela URL, você pode alterar isso e utilizar a [Geo Location](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) do HTML5.

Caso encontre mais problemas você pode verificar os erros encontrados pelo JavaScript dentro do Android abrindo o terminal e digitando o comando **adb logcat "CordovaLog:D *:S"**, todos os erros do JavaScript e todo o `output` do `console.log` deve ser apresentado.